# If i click any page on the website, Its redirecting to home page. Wordpress admin page also redirecting to home page

Tags: wordpress

I have a website(https://snehablogs.com/). If I click any page on the website, Its redirecting to home page. WordPress admin page also redirecting to home page. Because of this redirection am not able to login to the wordpress dashboard also. How can I stop this redirection to home page

How to fix this issue from GoDaddy cPanel

Website Name: https://snehablogs.com/